Find the domain for: $f(x)=\sqrt{\Big|\big||x-3|-2\big|-1\Big|-4}$
I tried to solve by making cases:
$$|||x-3|-2|-1|\ge4$$
$$-4\le|||x-3|-2|-1|\le4$$
and so on....
But my answer isn't right this way.
Is there some graphical method or something?
THANKS!

What is your answer from these cases?

I'm getting x∈[5,10]

You need $\Big|\big||x-3|-2\big|-1\Big|\geq4$. So either $\big||x-3|-2\big|-1\geq4$ or $\big||x-3|-2\big|-1\leq-4$. But the latter is impossible since it is a non-negative quantity subtract $1$. So you need $\big||x-3|-2\big|-1\geq4$, which means $\big||x-3|-2\big|\geq5$.
The same logic leads to $|x-3|-2\geq5$, or just $|x-3|\geq7$.
That means $x$ is at least $7$ away from $3$. In other words, $x\in(-\infty,-4]\cup[10,\infty)$.
